# function to call Splash screen in expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen

I'm trying to display the splashscreen whenever I navigate away from my app and come back,
I'm listening to the appstate even to detect if the app is active or not, but I don't know how to call the splashscreen when app is inactive.

```js
const [appState, setAppState] = useState(AppState.currentState);

// console.log(appState);
const handleAppStateChange = (state: any) => {
    if (state === "inactive")
    // if (state === "active") setInterval(\, 3000);
  };
useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", handleAppStateChange);
    return () => {
        AppState.removeEventListener("change", handleAppStateChange);
    };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do that, which is by creating a screen that has a fullscreen image / gif /video that is identical to the splash screen, and set a timeout inside that screen then navigate back to the app

Comment: how did you manage to add a video in the splash screen(when the app starts)?

Comment: the main idea is to make the splash screen static (image) of the first frame of the video, and after the splash screen which usually lasts about two seconds you make the main screen of the app the first screen as view with the video inside of it, this screen with the video inside you need to settimeout (for the length of the video) and the function of that timeout will call the rest of the app (main app)